# Is it possible for a class to always return a different object

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Say I have class A with class B as a property, how can I return A.B whenever a instance of A is assigned. For example:

```
public class A
{
    public B b {get; set;}
}

object x = A //Here I want to return A.b without casting it.
```

Essentially overloading the '=' operator or having a get statement for the class itself. What can I do here?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you edit your question to include why you want to do this, and the context for why you are asking it?

Comment: It sounds like you want an implicit cast from A to B.  However for that to work it would have to be `B x = instanceOfA;`  or `object x = (B)instanceOfA;` in which case it could be an explicit cast.

Comment: @juharr, Yeah that's it. I'm making a wrapper of sorts around a class with special functions that returns the original. I thought of basic inheritance but what I want is to return the class itself, not some derived version.

Comment: The [= operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator#operator-overloadability) cannot be overloaded in C#. Implicit casts cannot occur unless a polymorphic relationship exists between A and B. An extension method or member function that converts A <-> B is probably the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a job for the [implicit operator overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators), but I would very rarely use it, cause it can easily lead to confusion:

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A();
        B b = a;

        Console.WriteLine($"Name of b in a: {a.SomeB.Name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Name of b: {b.Name}");
    }
}

public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        SomeB = new B { Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };
    }

    public B SomeB { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator B(A a) => a.SomeB;
}

public class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Be aware that your example:

```
object x = A; // Here I want to return A.b without casting it.
```

Will never work, cause the desired type must be declared somewhere and `object` is not really the best candidate.